# Quickfixj internal debug logs

Tags: java, log4j, quickfixj

I'm using QuickFIXJ 1.5 version. I set logging level to INFO in my logj.properties file like that:

```
log4j.logger.quickfixj.msg.incoming=INFO  
log4j.logger.quickfixj.msg.outgoing=INFO  
log4j.logger.quickfixj.event=INFO
```

But in the application logs I see DEBUG logs of QuickFIXJ.

```
27-11-2014 10:20:34.172 8372 [SocketConnectorIoProcessor-0.0] DEBUG (FIXMessageDecoder.java:157) detected header: pos=0,lim=1695,rem=1695,offset=0,state=1
27-11-2014 10:20:34.172 8372 [SocketConnectorIoProcessor-0.0] DEBUG (FIXMessageDecoder.java:176) body length = 1671: pos=0,lim=1695,rem=1695,offset=17,state=3
27-11-2014 10:20:34.172 8372 [SocketConnectorIoProcessor-0.0] DEBUG (FIXMessageDecoder.java:200) message body found: pos=0,lim=1695,rem=1695,offset=1688,state=4
27-11-2014 10:20:34.172 8372 [SocketConnectorIoProcessor-0.0] DEBUG (FIXMessageDecoder.java:207) found checksum: pos=0,lim=1695,rem=1695,offset=1688,state=4
27-11-2014 10:20:34.173 8373 [SocketConnectorIoProcessor-0.0] DEBUG (FIXMessageDecoder.java:226) parsed message: pos=1695,lim=1695,rem=0,offset=1695,state=4
```

Why does it ignore the level setting in the log4j.properties?

Thanks

Comment: I added log4j.logger.quickfix.mina=ERROR and it solved. I think it was MINA logging.

Comment: nice looking logs, I like the colours